# React form Input Value

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hello I am trying to clone flowcv.io and I am stuck at how to get my form input to show at my preview pane onChange event happenin.

Here is a codesandbox link to the code
https://codesandbox.io/live/lm4vbj8

Comment: What is the specific error you're running into? Can you post the code thats causing you issues here?

Comment: You need to lift state up to the nearest common parent, and listen on the values used in the overview inside the PreviewPart.js with a ``useEffect``. It is a lot easier to answer, if you provide a more minimal example. Welcome to SO

Comment: @JonasGrønbek thank you looking into React-Hook-forms at the moment